# java.lang.module.FindException: Module c3p0 not found

Tags: java-11

I have created a JavaFX project that requires the use of c3p0 and jdk11

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module c3p0 not found, required by xxx
```

[image]

I have imported c3p0 and this is module info
[image]

```
module xxx {
requires javafx.controls;
requires javafx.fxml;
requires javafx.web;

requires org.controlsfx.controls;
requires com.dlsc.formsfx;
requires org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx;
requires org.kordamp.bootstrapfx.core;
requires eu.hansolo.tilesfx;
requires cn.hutool.core;
requires cn.hutool.log;
requires c3p0;
requires java.desktop;
requires spring.jdbc;
requires org.xerial.sqlitejdbc;

opens org.xxxx.x.xx to javafx.fxml;
exports org.xxxx.x.xx;
exports org.xxxx.x.xx.controller;
opens org.xxxx.x.xx.controller to javafx.fxml;}
```

this is build.gradle

```
plugins {
  id 'java'
  id 'application'
  id 'org.javamodularity.moduleplugin' version '1.8.12'
  id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.13'
  id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '2.25.0'
}

group 'org.xxxx'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

ext {
  junitVersion = '5.10.0'
}

sourceCompatibility = '11'
targetCompatibility = '11'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile).configureEach {
  options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

application {
  mainModule = 'org.xxx.xx'
  mainClass = 'org.xxx.xx.x.x'
}

javafx {
  version = '17.0.6'
  modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml', 'javafx.web', 'javafx.swing' ]
}

dependencies {
  implementation('org.controlsfx:controlsfx:11.1.2')
  implementation('com.dlsc.formsfx:formsfx-core:11.6.0') {
    exclude(group: 'org.openjfx')
  }
  implementation('org.kordamp.ikonli:ikonli-javafx:12.3.1')
  implementation('org.kordamp.bootstrapfx:bootstrapfx-core:0.4.0')
  implementation('eu.hansolo:tilesfx:11.48') {
    exclude(group: 'org.openjfx')
  }


  implementation group: 'org.fxmisc.richtext', name: 'richtextfx', version: '0.11.2'


  implementation 'cn.hutool:hutool-log:5.8.25'


  implementation 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.45.0.0'
  implementation 'com.mchange:c3p0:0.9.5.5'
  implementation 'org.springframework:spring-core:5.3.31'
  implementation 'org.springframework:spring-jdbc:5.3.31'

  testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitVersion}")
  testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}")
}

test {
useJUnitPlatform()}

jlink {
  imageZip = project.file("${buildDir}/distributions/app-${javafx.platform.classifier}.zip")
  options = ['--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages']
  launcher {
    name = 'app'
  }
}

jlinkZip {
  group = 'distribution'
}
```

I have checked the compatibility issues between jdk11 and c3p0, and it should not be related to this.
I am trying to change to another jdbc pool，I encountered the same problem

Please give me some ideas

Comment: When all other modules follow the reversed domain name convention, why do you assume that the name for this one module would consist of a single word? Since the module name is not shown anywhere, I can only guess, but how about something like `com.mchange.c3p0`? But maybe, your IDE has some option to show the module name, e.g. when opening the tree node or when hovering the mouse over it…

Comment: The c3p0 library jar file has no module info file. That means it's a "legacy" library without a module, and so it should not be mentioned in the `requires` line. See https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#using_libraries_that_are_not_modules